# Magento 2.X: Customer custom attribute is not saving from admin or code

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom-attributes, customer-attribute, eav-attributes

I have an issue I can't find why. I tried the issue on Magento 2.3.1 and 2.3.2.

I have created a module to add a new customer attribute. No issue for the moment. When I try to save the customer from the admin the value is not saved even when the field is in the admin form. Can you find my mistake?

[image]

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class UpgradeData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    protected $eavConfig;
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;

    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'exported_to_erp_at',
                [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Exported to erp at',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 88,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'system' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                ]
            );

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'exported_to_erp_at')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
                ]);

            $attribute->save();

        }
    }
}
```

As I said I tried to save with no success from the admin so I tried in Code. No success either.

```
$customer = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load(46431);
        $customer->setData("exported_to_erp_at", "toto");
        $customer->setCustomAttribute("exported_to_erp_at", "toto");
        $customer->save();

    //should work
    $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById(46431);
    $customer->setCustomAttribute("exported_to_erp_at", "toto");
    $this->_customerRepository->save($customer);
```

Do you have an idea?

**EDIT**

If this help I have not a clean installation. This is a migration with the magento migration tool from 1.7.x to 2.3.x

Comment: Any exception you are getting?

Comment: Nothing, not in system.log nor in exception.log. I have the same issue with 4 others attributes created by the migration tool

Comment: Can you try my answer once?

Comment: No change for the save. But the attribute disapeared in the customer admin form.

Comment: Give a try with vanila instance, For now put aside migrated. Your code is correct no issue once confirm with vanila for sure :)

Comment: It is working on a vanila instance. My issue is from the migration tool. After the migration my attribute is used in not form and is attached to no websites. I will make an answer soon to explain this in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the issue with the custom customer attribute.

My process was :

1. Create all my attributes with install/updrage scripts in my magento mpdules
2. Use the **Magento migration tool** to migrate from Magento 1 & 2
3. Test my code

The issue is that after the migration my attributes lost the used_in_forms value, were not assigned to any website.

I had to add a step in my migration to reset my customer attributes.

```
$attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', $attributeCode);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
        $attribute->setData('is_user_defined', false);
        $attribute->setData('is_system', false);
        $attribute->save();
```

This solved the problème for all the attributes needed.

Thx for your help.

Comment: Good point to share. +1 for answer

Answer (score 0):

Please change **user_defined** to **true** in UpgradeData.php as like below

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'exported_to_erp_at',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Exported to erp at',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 88,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
            ]
        );
```

Comment: It does not work for me, the only change is that the attribute is not displayed in the customer form in the admin anymore.

Comment: @Taschert, It should work, have you checked in the table, is_user_defined is set?

Comment: Yes, I have modified the value in "eav_attribute"

Comment: Did you modify now? or it was set once u run the upgradeData?

Comment: After the updrade date it was set to "0". I changed the value to 1 in the DB, emptied the cache, no change.

Comment: @Taschert, then it is not hitting to your code, since you changed user_defined to true, it should set 1. have u changed the version in module.xml?

Comment: I did not change the upgrade script, I only changed the data in the DB to "1". But it does not work with user_defined = true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97867/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-taschert).

Answer (score 0):

I did a script about Customer attribute in the past. My script worked perfectly so I put it on my gist.
Take a look, maybe it will help you.

https://gist.github.com/0-Sony/252311391be9e434a53e522709cc11be

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script and able to get value after save here is my script hope this helps

```
   <?php
        use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

        require '../../app/bootstrap.php';
        $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
        $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $eavSetup = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory');
        $setup = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface');
        $config = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config');

        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $eavSetup->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'start_time', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Start Time',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'system'=> false,
            'group'=> 'General',
            'position' => 160,
            'global' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
        ]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'end_time', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'label' => 'End Time',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'system'=> false,
            'position' => 160,
            'group'=> 'General',
            'global' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
        ]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'tail_lift', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Tail-Lift',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'system'=> false,
            'position' => 160,
            'group'=> 'General',
            'global' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'option' =>
                array (
                    'values' =>
                        array (
                            0 => 'Yes',
                            1 => 'No',
                        ),
                ),
        ]);

        $customAttribute =$config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'start_time');
        $customAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'] //list of forms where you want to display the custom attribute
        );
        $customAttribute->save();

        $customAttribute =$config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'end_time');
        $customAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'] //list of forms where you want to display the custom attribute
        );
        $customAttribute->save();

        $customAttribute =$config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'tail_lift');
        $customAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'] //list of forms where you want to display the custom attribute
        );
        $customAttribute->save();

//$eavSetup->removeAttribute('customer_address', 'tail_lift');

        $setup->endSetup();
echo "attribute adasddas";
```