# After Migrate catalog and category some custom attribute for category not saved

Tags: migration, data-migration, magento2.2.7, product-relations, magento1.9.0.1

I did migration for catalog and category in fresh `Magento1.9.0.1.` to `Magento2.2.7` migration was successfully completed after lot's of efforts :)

Actual issue here

But after that i have copied `catalog_` table to my current site that is already migrated before so i just want to update with newly added product from my old site.

Everything was working perfect but the issue is when try to save some custom attribute it was not saved.

So i have deleted previous attribute and create same with new `upgradeSchema`and it is working fine.

So what could be problem here that previously it was not working any relation table is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue with the custom customer attribute.

My process was :

1. Create all my attributes with install/updrage scripts in my magento mpdules
2. Use the **Magento migration tool** to migrate from Magento 1 & 2
3. Test my code

The issue is that after the migration my attributes lost the used_in_forms value, were not assigned to any website.

I had to add a step in my migration to reset my customer attributes.

```
$attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', $attributeCode);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
        $attribute->setData('is_user_defined', false);
        $attribute->setData('is_system', false);
        $attribute->save();
```

This solved the problème for all the attributes needed.

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/287137/72911)

Comment: Yes you might be right for customer attribute but my issue is with category attribute.I don't think we have to assign form to category attribute

Comment: try to indexer:reindex

Comment: already did it many times